# Doctrine Console error SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "SYSTEMUSER"

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm, laravel-5, ubuntu-14.04

I created a composer project with PHP 5.6.16, laravel/framework 5.1 and doctrine/orm 2.5.

Installed Postgresql 9.4 and Postgres Admim 3.

Create a admin role, a test database with a test table. Granted all permissions on database and tables to admin role.

```
$host   = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'test';
$dbuser = 'admin';
$dbpass = 'secret';

$connection = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=$dbname;host=$host", $dbuser, $dbpass);
if ($connection) {
   $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   $collection = $connection->query('select * from test');
   foreach ($collection as $row) {
      var_dump($row);
```

All works fine.

I created a cli-config.php file that loads the database config file from laraval framework with the same setup, creates a EntityManager through a service provider and returns a console runner:

```
$provider      = new App\Providers\DoctrineServiceProvider($app);
$entityManager = $provider->getEntityManager();

return \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);
```

I'm sure the EntityManager was created and i'm sure the correct database configuration was used.

When I run "vendor/bin/doctrine orm:validate-schema", i got an excetion:

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException] An exception occured in
>   driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: Ident authentication failed for
>   user "SYSTEMUSER"
>
> [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException] SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: Ident
>   authentication failed for user "SYSTEMUSER"
>
> [PDOException] SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: Ident authentication failed
>   for user "SYSTEMUSER"

Not that the user on exception message is different from the role used. The SYSTEMUSER is equals to my Ubuntu user.

I changed the dbuser to postgres and i got the same exception.

Anyone have clues about this?

Comment: My pg_hba.conf file:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
My postgresql.conf was changed:
listen_addresses = '*'

Comment: you see you have an answer already  in order to validate schema the doctrine uses the different used that have no access

Comment: What's the point of the cli-config.php file?